# Azure Function Func.exe Reload

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to have func.exe not lock dlls so you can rebuild?

In addition can func.exe reload the updated dlls?

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio 2017 tooling for Azure Functions, Azure Functions now supports publishing a class library as the implementation for one or more functions in a Function App. Several runtime improvements are made to make assemblies much more useful, such as shadow-copying managed assemblies to avoid file locking issues and restarting the Functions runtime to pick up newly deployed binaries.

Refer to below MSDN blog for more details -

[Publishing a .NET class library as a Function App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/)